# What do you call a person that holds sensitive information?

Tags: single-word-requests

All I have so far, is a pseudo-antonym of what I actually want: [Obscurantist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscurantist).
The word I need should be a person who was **unwillingly plagued** with **sensitive information**. It is more of a - I don't how to describe it - *pitiful* connotation. (To me, "infobearer" should work, allowing for the fact that such a word does not exist...)

For example, take Bob, who accidentally got himself exposed to top secret information of some organization. And now people are after him. He is a _____?

I need a single-word noun, not an adjective.

*Edit: would secret-keeper or secret-holder do the trick?*

Comment: Wouldn't it be brilliant if the word **Fidelius** (from Harry Potter) could mean this? :)

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco Took me a while to recollect, but yes! However I need the **noun** form. In the harry potter context, another name for the **Secret Keeper**.

Comment: In the Potterverse, the **Secret Keeper** is bound by the **Fidelius Charm**. But, I was basically saying that wouldn't it be great if a **fidelius** is a person who is bound by a secret. ;)

Comment: He's  burdened with a secret.

Comment: @HotLicks I need a single word...

Comment: I'd tell you, but it's a secret.

Comment: @HotLicks Haha very funny

Comment: Bob is now their [quarry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/quarry#h69946079393360). But he could have been their quarry for _any_ reason (other than holding their sensitive information).

Comment: @alwayslearning Thank you that helped a lot! Could you post that as an answer so we can end the thread? (Is that how it works? I'm not sure)

Comment: Glad that it helps but I'm afraid I can't post that as an answer to the question as it stands now (`What do you call a person that holds sensitive information?`). If you feel _quarry_ is the right answer, then you have to modify the question to remove reference to _holding confidential information_ and emphasize on the fact that they are after him irrespective of the reason.

Comment: @alwayslearning Understood. It worked in my context anyway

Comment: _Secretbearer_ and _secret holder_ are used in some technical contexts if you check Google Books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "***informant***", "***confidant***" and "***source***" all seem relevant to your word search, but you probably would want to qualify them with an adjective tailored to the exact description and meaning that you want to relate. Your example suggests both "hapless"(pitiable sense) or "beleaguered"(plagued sense) might work for you.

> For example, take Bob, who accidentally got himself exposed to top
>   secret information of some organization. And now people are after him.
>   He is a beleaguered **informant** to this day.
>
> For example, take Bob, who accidentally got himself exposed to top
>   secret information of some organization. And now people are after him.
>   He is now a hapless **source** with no place to hide?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informant
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/confidant
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/source

Comment: Informant is a close option to what I was looking for, thank you! (My previous option being quarry.)

Answer (score 0):

The proper term for a secret keeper is a “confidant.” When unwillingly pressed into service, they become a “reluctant confidant.” May not be the one word you are looking for, but captures the use case you’ve described.

Definition of confidant (cf. Merriam-Webster):

- one to whom secrets are entrusted.

Comment: It works in theory, but not in my context. Thank you anyway!